# How to parameterise a vector curve equation.

Tags: calculus, 3d, parametric, parametrization

I am trying to work out the 3D equation for a line describing a 3D vector field to visualize magnetic fields such that given a point in the vector field I can draw the field line that stems from that point.

A point in the vector field is defined by $f$ where:
$$
f(x, y, z)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(\frac{\lambda_i\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
m_{ix} - x \\
m_{iy} - y \\
m_{iz} - z
\end{pmatrix}
}{(m_{ix} - x)^2 + (m_{iy} - y)^2 + (m_{iz} - z)^2}\right)
$$
Here $n$ represents the number of magnetic poles where $m_{ix}, m_{iy}, m_{iz}$ are the positions of the given pole $i$ and $\lambda_i$ is some constant related to each pole.

Can also be re-written as:
$$
f(\alpha) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(\frac{\lambda_i(m_i-\alpha)}{||m_i-\alpha||^2}\right)
$$
Where $\alpha$ is a point in space and $m_i$ is point where the magnetic pole is positioned.

Currently I am visualizing the field lines by starting at a given point, $\beta$ and stepping some amount $t$ in the direction of the vector field at that point so:

$$\beta=\beta + tf(\beta)$$

Converting this into the vector line equation you get:

$$
\frac{x-\beta_x}{f(\beta)_x}=\frac{y-\beta_y}{f(\beta)_y}=\frac{z-\beta_z}{f(\beta)_z}
$$

Essentially describes a line in 3D where the direction is a function of $x,y,z$ (so a 3D curve, right?).

The problem is that, from here, if I want to find points along this curve I need to provide some value for either $x$, $y$ or $z$, however for a given value of $x$, $y$ or $z$ there might not be a valid solution (the point I selected does not exist on the curve). So to fix this I believe I'll need to parameterise the line equation such that given a value $t$ I get a point $x,y,z$ on the line but I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! <> It sounds a lot like you're trying to implement _Euler's method_, an iterative numerical algorithm for solving first-order differential equations given an initial condition. The idea is to index $\beta$: Start at $\beta_0$, fix a time step $dt$, and iteratively define$$\beta_{n+1}=\beta_n+dt\,f(\beta_n),\quad n\geq0$$for as many steps as desired. You might search the site (or the web) for more details as needed.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Sorry if I wasn't very clear in the question but I am trying to move away from Euler's method since in code it runs quite slow. I am currently already using Euler's method but I wish to parameterise the equation such that I do not need to use Euler's method in an iterative approach.

Comment: I see; is the number of magnetic particles large, so that calculating $f$ is costly? <> Without a closed-form solution you'll need some iterative numerical scheme. I'm not a numerical analyst, but can't imagine you'll find a faster numerical algorithm than Euler's method.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yeah, I was looking up at other methods such as https://x-engineer.org/plot-vector-field/ where they do something similar in converting a vector field to a line equation, but the equation they presented in the example is trivial to integrate compared to what I have. In attempting to do this I thought parameterising the equation may help leading to this discussion.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might be able to pre-compute sampled values of your field on a lattice, then _approximate_ Euler's method by interpolating lattice values.